# "to stay focus" or "to stay focused" which of the phrases is correct?

Tags: tense, adjectives

I am a little confused on which is correct. Is it right use "to stay focused, we ..." or say "to stay focus, we...."
Please I need clarifications on the uses of the two 2 phrases mentioned above.

Comment: Stay focused.  Keep your focus.

Answer (score 1):

The second one "stay focused" is correct.

"Focused" is an adjective, "focus" is a verb (at least, it seems like one here; it can also be a noun). You cannot put a verb here. One grammatical alternative with a verb is to use "keep" with the -ing form:  Keep focusing.

With a noun, you would need an article after stay: "Stay a person".

Comment: Both focus and focused are correct. You can check the usage in Google.

Comment: Which is "the second one"?  The title and the body of the question give the options in different orders.  I believe you're saying that the second option in the title ("stay focused") is correct, but you could make this clearer in your answer.